# How to produce the job title when exporting using Get-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group |
  select @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"}, Name, Title |
  Export-Csv C:\Srptupd\Groupmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

How can I get the Name and job title? My code produces the name but no Job Title.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the AD cmdlets available right now, but I'm pretty sure that Get-ADGroupMember gives you some basic details about the members of the group, but not a full ADUser object with all of the properties (including Title). You'll probably need to do something like:

```
select @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"}, Name, @{l='Title';e={Get-ADUser $_.SAMAccountName -Properties Title | select -ExpandProperty Title}} |
```

That's without testing, but something like that should work -- you basically have to use Get-ADUser to go get the properties you want that aren't returned by Get-ADGroupMember.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Let me try to play around with it

Comment: Your best bet is to do "Get-ADGroupMember -id $group | select -first 1 *" to see all of the properties you get from that cmdlet. From there you can figure out the best thing to pass on to Get-ADUser to get the Title property.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -id $Group | Get-ADUser -Properties Title | select Name, Title
```